# change settings for celery chain of group in Django

Tags: python, django, celery, multitasking

Suppose I have the following function in my tasks.py:

```
def func():
    tasks = []
    myArray=range(1,100000)
    x_tasks = [add(i,i+1) for i in myArray]
    tasks.append(group(x_tasks))
    tasks.append(divide(400,20))
    task = chain(*tasks)
    task()
```

Add and divide are two simple functions.
As you know, having chain of groups makes the chord_unlock task. I am wondering how I can change its settings like how to change the default_retry_delay for that? For other functions like add and divide we are able to do this in their decorators like:

```
@shared_task(default_retry_delay=240)
def add(x,y):
    return x+y
```

But I don't know how to change settings for a chord_unlock task that is created implicitly using chain of groups.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
I needed to use the app instance created from celery as following:

```
import os

from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'annotate.settings')

app = Celery('hawkeye')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

app.tasks['celery.chord_unlock'].default_retry_delay = 300
app.tasks['celery.chord_unlock'].max_retries = None
```

In fact, `app.tasks` is a dictionary that contains all tasks, through which we can change their settings.